Custom notification is not displayed when received on the front of the ANDROID screen
I am trying to create a custom message and in all the situations it creates. The design is created only after the message goes to the Android notification thread, but in the first moments before it goes there and it is displayed at the front of the screen, the message is displayed according to the default NOTIFICATION ANDROID, is there a solution to make and change the TITLE and TEXT of the message even when it is at the front of the screen or change the settings of Its default?
This is my code : custom_notification.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>


This is my code java:
private void showCustomNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channelId = "custom_channel_id";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Custom Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    RemoteViews customView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    customView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_title, title);
    customView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_message, message);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) 
            .setCustomContentView(customView)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()) 
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}


In NOTIFICATION, when the user receives this message, he sees nothing and I want just my design to be in it

private void showCustomNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String channelId = "custom_channel_id";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Custom Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

RemoteViews customView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
customView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_title, title);
customView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_message, message);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(title) // Set default title
        .setContentText(message) // Set default message
        .setCustomContentView(customView)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

}
try it im not sure

Not good. Note I don't want the default Android .setContentTitle(title) // Set default title
.setContentText(message) I have a lot of problems with this

can answer that Or is this too difficult a question?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
